# TypeError:Super expression must either be null or a function in react native

Tags: react-native, module, typeerror

i'm trying to make a simple page with a text in React-native:

```
import { Image,StyleSheet,Text,View,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native"
import React from "react"

export class App extends React.component{
  render() {
    return <View>
    <Text>hello iran</Text>
    </View>
  };
};
```

it built Successfully But it shows two errors in the simulator:

TypeError:Super expression must either be null or a function

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Why does this happen?  What is the reason for this error?
How to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `Component` should be capitalized.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome :)